# id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey] to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to build a camera app in swift, I searched some code on the Internet and I found this lines of code.

```
(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error {

NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - enter");

BOOL RecordedSuccessfully = YES;
if ([error code] != noErr)
{
    // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
    id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
    if (value)
    {
        RecordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
    }
}
...
```

How can I write **id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];** in swift?

I try with:

```
value = error.userInfo[AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey]
```

but it show me this error: **'NSString is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex'**

Comment: Give it a shot, what do you think it will look like?

Comment: I adjust, one moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can write this line of code in swift this way:

```
var value: AnyObject! = error.userInfo[AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey]
```

UPD:

You're using xCode beta version less than 5, according to this warning:

> 'NSString is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex'

Update it!